# Date and time comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to SQL Server. My problem is to write a SQL query that compares `datetime` column with some fixed date AND time, but I would like to make it independent of language settings (regarding date and time values).

Comment: `Where YourDateTimeField = '2016-09-08 13:57'` ... What is your question...?

Comment: The `DateTime` type is not dependent on language or locale. There is also no timezone or offset persisted with the `DateTime` type.

Comment: What I thought that maybe it should be 2016/09/08 or 08/09/2016 or... I knew the syntax that you wrote, but I thought  it should be changed  according to language settings on PC where SQL Server sits.

Comment: Link, that I obviously misunderstood according to Siyual is: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/396228/compare-two-datetime-using-sql-server , which I thought deals with language settings.

Comment: What is the code you tried, and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't store a `DateTime` in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte numerical value. So when stored, there's no issue with language dependent formats or anything like that.

When using string literals representing date and time, however, there are many formats supported by SQL Server. The way to go is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server for date and time looks like this:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` - note here: this format has dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that DateTime is not stored as a string, but string should be written when writing SQL query. The rest of your answer I didn't know, so I mark it as useful to me. Thank you marc_s